# Liferay openAM configuration error

Tags: java, liferay, single-sign-on, openam, opensso

I'm using openAM to configure openSSO on Liferay, after i changed everything inside Liferay backend and in the portal-ext.properties i'm getting this error in the console

```
Exception in thread "liferay/scheduler_dispatch-215" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.InetAddressUtil$LocalHostNameHolder
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.InetAddressUtil.getLocalHostName(InetAddressUtil.java:32)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.SchedulerEngineUtil._auditSchedulerJobs(SchedulerEngineUtil.java:455)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.SchedulerEngineUtil.auditSchedulerJobs(SchedulerEngineUtil.java:92)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.messaging.SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.receive(SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.java:103)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:63)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:114)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:671)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:582)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Can anyone tell me what is this problem or issue?

I'm using openAM 10 and Liferay 6.1.20ee

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same exception with no further clue.

Comment: I have the same problem when no inet addr is defined on my eth0. When pluging an Internet cable, it starts...

Answer (score 1):

Just to make you not looking at the wrong direction ... this issue is not related to OpenAM integration.